# Running AJAX from PHP Controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am sorry to sound confusing but I will try to explain in the best way possible.

In the controller I have a function search

```
public function search(){
   /*
    I run my logics and get few URL from 
    where I need to fetch further data
    the urls are saved in the URL array

     $urls[0] = "http://url1.com/search1";
     $urls[1] = "http://url2.com/search2";

    I then set this in data variable and send it to view 
    so that It can be run in AJAX

    I tired running get_file_contents but it executes 
    in series one after the other URL. 
    If there are 10 URL (5 secs per URL) the over all processing time 
    increases drastically

   */

   $data["urls"] = $urls;

   $resp = $this->load->view('ajaxer',$data,TRUE);

   /* based on the $resp i need to run further business logic's */

}
```

Now the $resp is actually giving me only the HTML code. It is not executing the HTML and hence the ajax is not run.

Any thoughts on how to execute this will be really helpful.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: The problem is probably because you don't include a `success` item in the ajax options. The option `success` is a function that receives the output of the controller. In that function is where you manipulate the html to use the returned data. Add the javascript code where you make the ajax call and the html of the view to be updated.

Comment: @DFriend I do have a success option. If its a success, i update a particular div html. However, the div is empty and I get the full HTML code in the $resp

Comment: `$resp` contains html because that is the intended purpose of `load->view('someview');`  - to return the contents (typically html) in the file "someview". A clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve would be very helpful. For instance, what do you plan to do with the search URLs?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutelly ok. But your javascript is not getting any response data (only headers), because you are not returning any output.

If you want to "execute your HTML" you need to change the line with view to this:

```
$this->load->view('ajaxer',$data);
```

or this:

```
$resp = $this->load->view('ajaxer',$data,TRUE);
echo $resp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to echo output in the controller. Apart from this you need few minor modification in your function.

```
public function search(){
    /*
     I run my logics and get few URL from
     where I need to fetch further data
     the urls are saved in the URL array

      $urls[0] = "http://url1.com/search1";
      $urls[1] = "http://url2.com/search2";

     I then set this in data variable and send it to view
     so that It can be run in AJAX

     I tired running get_file_contents but it executes
     in series one after the other URL.
     If there are 10 URL (5 secs per URL) the over all processing time
     increases drastically

    */

    // You need to check either request came from Ajax request or not. If not it will echo passed string. It prevents to access this function besides Ajax request
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo "Ajax Requests allowed.";
        die;
    }

    $data["urls"] = $urls;

    $resp = $this->load->view('ajaxer',$data,TRUE);

    // Standard way to set response for output in json format.
    // @param status will help to check all things goes correct or not. if not please pass false on the basis or your feature's requirement
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('status'=>true,'response'=>$resp)));

    // Standard way to get output set above step.
    $string = $this->output->get_output();
    echo $string;
    exit();
    /* based on the $resp i need to run further business logic's */

}
```

Updated code is here. Hope you find your answer